# extra function in nodejs for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have a simple for loop like so :

```
for(var foo in bar) {
    var x = bar[foo];
    console.log(x);
}
```

However, I get this as my response:

```
{...} // An object as expected
{...} // An object as expected
{...} // An object as expected
[Function]
```

What is this extra function and how can we remove it?

Comment: Probably some other property of `bar` that you don't want, [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Comment: Could you post sample bar?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is your friend

Comment: What’s the name of the key (`console.log(foo, x)`)? If it’s on `Object.prototype`, 1) use a filtered loop with `hasOwnProperty` 2) don’t extend `Object.prototype` with enumerable properties 3) don’t extend `Object.prototype` 4) use `Object.keys(bar).forEach` instead

Comment: @ssube how is hasOwnProperty different from `typeof `? I've added `if (typeof x == 'undefinded') continue;` but that doesn't do it; I had to do `if (typeof x == 'undefinded' || typeof x == 'function') continue;` to get it to work. Somehow, I don't think that both typeofs are necessary

Comment: @DaveWoodhall `hasOwnProperty` ensures that the property is defined on the instance, not provided by inheritance. It skips prototype methods and the like.

Answer (score 0):

The extra function is likely the object prototypes constructor, use hasOwnProperty to check for the property in your loop.